Removing Epsilon Productions
I am trying to remove an epsilon transition from the following CFG:
S-> AB
A → aA | ABA | ε
B → b | c
I came up with this:
S → AB | B
A → aA | ABA | a | BA | AB
B → b | c
However, I am not sure about the BA | AB part. Should I also make them as B(ε) | (ε)B resulting in:
A → aA | ABA | a | B
or should I just let this (A → aA | ABA | a | BA | AB)  be?

While considering $ABA$ and the fact that $A$ can be $\epsilon$, you should add non-terminals that result from picking all possible combinations of $A$ and removing them. In this case, we have three possibilities: $BA$ (if the left $A$ is $\epsilon$), $AB$ (if the right $A$ is $\epsilon$) and $B$ (if the both $A$s are $\epsilon$). So, the final production for $A$ would be $A \rightarrow aa \;|\; ABA \;|\; BA \;|\; AB \;|\; B$.
Hope this helps!
-- SG

This is noted thank you for this.
